# Need help overriding Material UI styling

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio, material-ui

I've created a app bar using Material UI.
I need to add a couple finishing touches :

1. Rounded Input Base - so border radius
2. Changing the colour of the app bar (so overriding Material UI's colours)
   The issue I'm having is because I used the example on the material UI website to create it, it's difficult to input new code into it to override what has been imported and also what is there.

This is the code:

```
const Search = styled("div")(({ theme }) => ({
  position: "relative",
  borderRadius: theme.shape.borderRadius,
  backgroundColor: alpha(theme.palette.common.black, 0.15),
  "&:hover": {
    backgroundColor: alpha(theme.palette.common.black, 0.25),
  },
  marginLeft: 0,
  width: "100%",
  [theme.breakpoints.up("sm")]: {
    marginLeft: theme.spacing(1),
    width: "auto",
  },
}));

const StyledInputBase = styled(InputBase)(({ theme }) => ({
  color: "inherit",
  "& .MuiInputBase-input": {
    padding: theme.spacing(1, 1, 1, 0),
    // vertical padding + font size from searchIcon
    paddingLeft: `calc(1em + ${theme.spacing(4)})`,
    transition: theme.transitions.create("width"),
    width: "100%",
    [theme.breakpoints.up("sm")]: {
      width: "12ch",
      "&:focus": {
        width: "20ch",
      },
    },
  },
}));

const SearchIconWrapper = styled("div")(({ theme }) => ({
  padding: theme.spacing(0, 2),
  height: "100%",
  position: "absolute",
  pointerEvents: "none",
  display: "flex",
  alignItems: "center",
  justifyContent: "center",
}));

function appbar() {
  return (
    <div className="navbar">
      <AppBar position="static" className="appbar">
        <Toolbar>
          <Typography>Hello World</Typography>
          <Search>
            <SearchIconWrapper>
              <SearchIcon
                className="searchicon"
                sx={{ transform: "scale(1.3)" }}
              />
            </SearchIconWrapper>
            <StyledInputBase
              placeholder="Search for more here"
              inputProps={{ "aria-label": "search" }}
            />
          </Search>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you just add !important?

```
borderRadius: theme.shape.borderRadius !important,
```

Comment: Are you asking?

Comment: To the css file or the styles constant, also I'd need an actual value in order for it to do something

Comment: @FA66 add classes to your elements and create custom css values for the classes. To find out what value you want you will need to experiment with it. This is a good resource [link](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp)

Comment: I've tried to do that @user10381291, it won't override the material UI stuff

Answer (score 0):

Material UI supports passing a color prop to the app bar. First define a theme file and pass it to the Theme Provider of your app like this. You can refer to the documentation [here](https://mui.com/customization/theming/)

```
import * as React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { red } from '@mui/material/colors';
import { ThemeProvider, createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';

const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: red[500],
    },
    secondary: {
      main: red[500],
    },
  },
});

function App() {
  return <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>...</ThemeProvider>;
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

With your theme created you can pass the value to the app bar like this

```
  <AppBar color="primary" position="static" className="appbar">
  </AppBar>
```

Not sure how you want to pass the border radius. but you can do something like this

```
const StyledInputBase = styled(InputBase)(({ theme }) => ({
  color: "inherit",
  "& .MuiInputBase-input": {
    padding: theme.spacing(1, 1, 1, 0),
    // vertical padding + font size from searchIcon
    borderRadius: `4px 0 0 4px`,
    paddingLeft: `calc(1em + ${theme.spacing(4)})`,
    transition: theme.transitions.create("width"),
    width: "100%",
    [theme.breakpoints.up("sm")]: {
      width: "12ch",
      "&:focus": {
        width: "20ch",
      },
    },
  },
}));
```

There are definitely other ways to pass the styles like this

```
<StyledInputBase
  placeholder="Search for more here"
  inputProps={{
    "aria-label": "search",
    classes: {
      root: classes.input,
    },
  }}
/>;
```

Let me know if you have any difficulty, I will be happy to help.